# Can I change the standby time for my monitor with ddcutil?

Tags: monitor

When I restart my computer, DPMS turns my main monitor quickly and it adds a delay to being able to see my bootloader for selection. I do not want to turn off DPMS, only change the standby time.

`flashrom` has support for MSTAR-equipped displays, which is what ddcutil is telling me what my monitor is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the developer of [ddcutil](http://www.ddcutil.com)

The only feature in the Monitor Control Command Set relating to DPMS is xd6 (Power Mode).  There is nothing to adjust the standby time.   It is conceivable that one of the features in the manufacturer reserved range (xeo-xff) does so.  Only trial and error can determine this.  Your best bet is the On Screen Display.

Unless you have specific knowledge, I wouldn't put much stock in the controller manufacturer/model number (feature xc9). I've yet to observe a functionality pattern.